# Trim White Spaces From Beginning and End of Form Fields in React-JsonSchema-Form

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

I'm using react-jsonschema-form 1.2.1 to build a form based on a JsonSchema (v7).  I want to automatically trim leading and trailing white spaces from certain text box input fields when a user presses submit on the form.  Since the form is completely rendered by the `<Form>` element of the react-jsonschema-form module, I don't know how I can do this with JavaScript code.

Does react-jsonschema-form have trim capabilities?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There a few different ways to do this, none as simple as flag to trim all string data though.

1. You can define a custom widget and use the uiSchema to designate specific fields to use this widget. This widget can then trim the value before using the native onChange function to notify the form that its value was changed, refer to: https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/#custom-widget-components
2. You can define your own TextWidget (reserved name, refer to: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/widgets/TextWidget.js => https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form/blob/master/src/components/widgets/BaseInput.js) and then use this TextWidget to replace all string-type fields:

```
const myWidgetOverrides = { TextWidget };

render() {
    return (
        <Form schema={schema}
            widgets={this.myWidgetOverrides}
        />
    );
}
```

3. You can override the validate function inside a new class component that extends the React JSONSchema Form class:

```
class TrimmedStringForm extends Form {
    validate(formData, schema) {
        formData = trimAllStrings(formData);
        return super.validate(formData, schema);
    }
}
```

or define your own validation function (refer to:
https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation/#custom-validation) to trim all/specific string-type fields from formData before it is passed into the submit function.

Comment: Thanks @mirage! Sorry for the delayed response, I've been on vaca.  I'll try option #2, this seems the most favorable for my situation.  I'll let you know how it goes.